# chart.js x-axes date-format not working

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I am using chart.js for my application and I have a problem with the dateformat in my x-Axes. My chart looks like this:

[image]

Example Data:

```
[{x:"2018-03-06", y:-0.66}, {x:"2018-03-06", y:-0.499},{x:"2018-03-06", y:-0.199}]
```

I tried with new Date() and without new Date() Constructor but it is not working. Can someone help me?

**My code:**

```
  drawChartMultipleColumns(chartData){
    const positions = Object.keys(chartData.data[0][0]).filter((item)=> item.indexOf('tradedate') == -1)

    positions.forEach((pos)=>{

      this.chartItems.push({data:chartData.data[0].map((item)=>{
          return {
            x:new Date(item['data']),
            y:item[pos] * 100
          }
        })
      });
    })


    this.options = LINECHARTXAXES;
    this.chartItems.forEach((item, index)=>{
      this.data.datasets.push({'label': 'test', data: item.data, fill: false, borderColor: '#4bc0c0'})
    })
  }
```

**Option:**

```
 export const LINECHARTXAXES = {
      responsive: true,
      tooltip: {enable: false},
      elements: {point: {radius: 0}},
      title: {display: true, text: 'Laufzeit [Jahr]', fontSize: 16, position: 'bottom'},
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: '%'
          },
          ticks: {
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'bottom'

        }]
      }
    }
```